# How to login in to Reddit with PRAW?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Im trying to learn `PRAW`. Doing everything according to official documentations but start getting login error (output below)

What do I wrong? How can I fix that?
All `creds` are correct.

```
import json
import praw
import requests
 
subr = 'test'
credentials = 'client_secrets.json'
 
with open(credentials) as f:
    creds = json.load(f)
 
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=creds['client_id'],
                     client_secret=creds['client_secret'],
                     user_agent=creds['user_agent'],
                     redirect_uri=creds['redirect_uri'],
                     pasword=creds['password'],
                     username=creds['username'])

title = "PRAW documentation"
url = "https://praw.readthedocs.io"
reddit.subreddit("test").submit(title, url=url)
```

Output:

```
RedditAPIException: USER_REQUIRED: 'Please log in to do that.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **the easiest way to login to reddit using PRAW...**

the easiest way to login to reddit using PRAW is by using this code from [the docs](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/quick_start.html)

> - client_id is the "script" you are given by reddit when you create your app
> - client_secret is the API key that you are given by reddit from when you create the app
> - password is your reddit accounts password
> - user_agent is the description of your app
> - and username is your username of your reddit account

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(
client_id="client_id",
client_secret="client_secret",
password="password",
user_agent="user_agent",
username="username",
)
```